# Rackmount server with a PCI-e x16 slot that will accept a double-width card?

Tags: hardware, pci-express

I'm looking to buy a rackmount server that will accommodate an [NVIDIA Tesla C1060](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_tesla_c1060_us.html) for testing purposes by our developers. The card is a dual-width PCI-e 16x card, and I'm having trouble finding a rackmount server that will fit it. Is anyone aware of a server that would fit this card.

I'm well aware that there are rackmount versions of the Tesla, but we're specifically getting just the C1060 for a trial.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HP DL380 G6 ([CLICKY FOR LINK](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/en/WF25a/15351-15351-3328412-241644-241475-3884082.html))

Comment: These are great boxes.  Have one now with a fax card that takes up 2 slots.

Comment: agreed, did you know that the various DL380 generations account for 40% of all pizza-box servers ever sold! oddly the documentation states that they can't take a double-height card but I think it's just a cut'n'paste error from a smaller server as they definitely can.

Answer (score 0):

Supermicro have announced a new range of 1U servers that are optimised for Tesla [cards. The SS6016GT-TF-TC2](http://www.supermicro.com/GPU/) can take one or two of the C1060 cards. Not sure of availability yet - they've been announced, but there doesn't seem to be any more information available.

Some of Supermicro's older systems, such as the [SS6015X](http://www.supermicro.com/products/system/1U/6015/SYS-6015X-3.cfm) may also work, as they have suitable space available. Cooling will possibly be an issue in these systems however - there's no fans directed over the PCI card space, whereas the SS6016GT has fans covering this area.